# java- dto to model convert Error

Tags: java, spring, maven

i have dto and model layer.And i want convert dto to model layer like this code.How do i fix this error?I have all getter and setter i need

model/travel class

```
    public Travel convert(TravelDTO dto) {
    this.setTravelID(dto.getTravelID());
    this.setTravelCost(dto.getTravelCost());
    this.setTravelStart(dto.getTravelStart());
    this.setTravelEnd(dto.getTravelEnd());
    this.setLocation(dto.getLocation());
    this.setTravelPurpose(dto.getTravelPurpose());
    this.setUser(new User().convert(dto.getUser()));
    return this;
}
```

dto/travelDTO class

```
    public TravelDTO convert(Travel entity) {
    this.setTravelID(entity.getTravelID());
    this.setTravelCost(entity.getTravelCost());
    this.setTravelStart(entity.getTravelStart());
    this.setTravelEnd(entity.getTravelEnd());
    this.setLocation(entity.getLocation());
    this.setTravelPurpose(entity.getTravelPurpose());
    this.setUser(new UserDTO().convert(entity.getUser()));
    return this;
}
```

userDto / convert code

```
    public UserDTO convert(User entity) {
    this.setUserID(entity.getUserID());
    this.setFirstName(entity.getFirstName());
    this.setLastName(entity.getLastName());
    this.setManagerId(entity.getManagerId());
    this.setPassword(entity.getPassword());
    this.setRegNumber(entity.getRegNumber());
    this.setUserName(entity.getUserName());
    this.setDepartment(new DepartmentDTO().convert(entity.getDepartment()));
    this.setTravel(new TravelDTO().convert(entity.getTravel()));

    return this;
}
```

[image: ERROR]

Comment: Can you also post the code of `UserDTO#convert`?

Comment: @nico added the code

Answer (score 1):

The error message explains the issue :). It says the entity.getUser() is returning a list of users. But the method accepts one User object.

Comment: Tables are between many to many relationship travel and user.So i need list for convert layer.how do i convert?

Comment: Change the convert method in the UserDTO to accepts list of users or overload the method with list of users. Then iterate through the list and convert them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your entity.getUser() is returning List whereas your convert method of UserDTO is expecting single User model object.

Comment: Tables are between many to many relationship travel and user.So i need list for convert layer.how do i convert?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from you screenshot, UserDTO.convert method accepts argument of type User, and you are trying to pass argument with type List. I guess, the possible solution is to make Travel.getUser() return User instead of List.

**UPDATE**

You may iterate through your list of Users, converting each one to UserDTO and then adding it to collection, then passing it as an argument to this.setUser. Something like this: `

```
List<UserDTO> userDTOs = new ArrayList<>();
List<User> users = entity.getUser();
for (User user : users) { 
    UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO.convert(user);
    userDTOs.add(userDTO);
} 
this.setUser(userDTOs);
```

And please pay attention that your TravelDTO class has `List<User> user` field. I guess, it should be `List<UserDTO> users`.

Comment: Tables are between many to many relationship travel and user.So i need list for convert layer.how do i convert?

Comment: Please, take a look at my post update above your comment.